# GORM (Hibernate) tries to map non-domain classes; gives DuplicateMappingException

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, shiro, grails-2.2

I am upgrading my Grails app from version 2.1.0. Prior to this upgrade the application was behaving fine. I downloaded and set-up the new version of Grails (initially I tried version 2.2.1 but tried going to 2.2.2 today) and did a Grails upgrade on my app.

Since that upgrade my app won't start, citing a DuplicateMappingException.

```
DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: User refers to both com.mycompany.myapp.User and net.security.User (try using auto-import="false")
```

or

```
DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: Role refers to both net.security.Role and com.mycompany.myapp.Role (try using auto-import="false")
```

**So it seems to me that GORM for some reason thinks it needs to map these `net.security` classes to the database.**

`Role` and `User` are domain classes I use with the Shiro security plugin for Grails.

I have tried adding `autoImport false` to the mapping block in my domain classes. This caused problems in other parts of the system where `User` or `Role` are used. I haven't pursued this further because I am sure that there shouldn't be a conflict here.

So I'm looking if anyone has an idea what might be causing this, or some things I might try to fix it.

FYI I have tried a Grails clean on the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that the `net.security` classes are not some random classes as I was thinking. `net.security` is the default package for the Shiro OpenID plugin classes. So earlier in the project we added `User` and `Role` classes with our own package instead of using the ones that came with the Shiro OpenID plugin. At that point we must have removed the corresponding classes from the `grails-app` and `src/groovy/net/security` directories in the `.grails/<version>/projects/<project>/plugins/shiro-openid-0.5` directory. When I upgraded to Grails 2.2.2 the plugin recreated these file and they are conflicting with the ones in our project.

For now I have deleted these class files manually, but perhaps there is a way to delete them automatically in `BuildConfig.groovy`? That's a problem for another day though.